# Tips/Suggestions needed for implementing a particular view in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I need to implement a rotary dialer similar to [this](http://www.4shared.com/photo/nfVhN9Vn/rotary_dialer.html)

I have the following queries:

1) What are the widgets that I should use, in order to implement this rotary dialer?
2) What is the best and most optimal design pattern that I should use to implement this rotary dialer?

Any help in this regard, which would help me kick-start implementing this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Anees

Comment: the only one things for you help is use OPENGL ES for this type of design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of the Rotary Dialer Free for Android (see [Rotary Dialer Free on Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=nl.wellknown.rotarydialer))

For this, I used OpenGl10 (for easy rotating and drawing the textures).

Kind regards,
Marcel